# SQL Management Studio connection handshake error when connecting through tunnel

Tags: sql-server, tcp, ssms, ssh-tunnel, handshake

While trying to connect to SQL Server through SSMS I get the following Error

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 -  The specified network name is no longer available.)  (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I have a tunnel connection to a jumpserver open that should have access to the DB Server.
Pinging the DBServers IP Address / Domain name from the jumpserver reaches it without a problem.
Connecting with SSMS through a VM inside the network of the DB Server also works (I also need to go through the jumpserver for that)
The tunneling configuration is double checked and should be correct.

I enabled every Protocol in the SQL Server Configuration Manager and double checked the IPs. I enabled access through remote connections to the SQL Server Instance. Connecting via a VM inside the same subnet works fine. Only when connecting through a tunnel do I get this issue.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see an issue like this when using SQL Login authentication. Are you attempting to use Windows authentication?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm currently using SQL Server Authentication with a user I know usualy works. The windows user on my local laptop is a different one then the user on my VM. Thats why i currently cant use windows authentication. nevertheless using both types of login results in the same error (with bogus login credentials too)

Comment: Windows Firewall on the target server? Probably you're presenting a source IP in a different CIDR block than you would be from the VM inside the network.